# Django crontab doesnot execute at specific time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cron

I am scheduling a cron job at a specific time but code below doesn't work

> ```
> ('22 20 * * *', 'sentimentor.cron.sentiment')
> ```

The above code should execute at 8:22 pm UTC daily

But if I change the code to the following it works

> ```
> ('*/1 * * * *', 'sentimentor.cron.sentiment')
> ```

The above code will execute every 1 minute which is not required

I tried many different things please help me if any solution avilable for this.

Comment: Is your timezone UTC?

Comment: what is the value of  /etc/timezone , or /etc/default/cron

Comment: Timezone is also UTC and I am scheduling the cron job based on UTC time only

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of timezone difference.
If your system time is in IST (Indian Standard Time) i.e., UTC + 5:30 then you have to add 5 hr, 30 minutes in UTC while adding a cron. Similarly it will work for other timezones. First you have to verify if your system timezone is UTC or not.

If your timezone is IST then your cron should be:

```
('52 1 * * *', 'sentimentor.cron.sentiment')
```

In linux or mac find your timezone using:

```
date +'%z %Z'
```

Comment: Please share your findings or if this solution works for you. @Jay

Comment: Thanks for answering I checked my timezone its IST but the timezone of django project is different right its UTC ? If I am not wrong .

Comment: By default, Django would pick system time. If it was the only problem then the given solution will work. You can upvote and mark the answer as accepted so that others having similar problems can benefit from it.

Comment: Hey I tried using both IST time and UTC time and tried to test it , but it didnt wrk

Comment: I also tried the above thing by making all timezones homogenous i.e. i set all timexones to UTC but that didnt work please suggest me any other fix